# Using python to stash git changes, switch branches, commit files, switch back and undo stash

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am about to automate adding a large number of files to a specific branch of my git repository. I want to be certain I'm not about to cause major problems for myself.

The issue is I have a code base with which I run several hundreds of experiments. I want the results to be automatically stored to their own branch, while leaving the master branch unaffected (i.e. The master branch will NOT track experimental results). I am not as familiar with the `stash` command as I'd like to be, and want to be certain I'm using it correctly.

```
import subprocess
from git import Repo

# Stash changes and switch to result_branch
subprocess.run(["git", "stash"])
subprocess.run(["git", "checkout", "result_branch"], check=True) 

#add_results_to_repo() -- Calls method that finds result files and uses Repo.git.add to add them to repo
#git_commit() -- Calls method that uses Repo.git.commit to commit branches

# Return to master branch and undo stash
subprocess.run(["git", "checkout", "master"], check=True)
subprocess.run(["git", "stash", "pop"], check=True)
```

I use `subprocess` to switch branches, because I had trouble using `Repo`. I use `subprocess` to stash, because I'm lazy and I'm familiar with `subprocess.run`. Perhaps:

```
 repo.git.stash() # To create stash, and
 repo.git.stash('pop') # To restore stash??
```

Is the approach I'm taking a valid one, or do I risk causing all sorts of repository problems for myself?

Comment: are you going to create a separate branch for each result? or do you want to store each result of the iteration in the same ```result_branch```. Also, is there a reason why you want to create those branches? what is the use case? have you considered `git patch`?

Comment: @Or Y - All results get saved to the same branch. I want to create it, so that I can share results across machines, but easily get rid of them (delete branch) when I'm done, without complicating  the history of actual code development.

Comment: I recommend *avoiding* `git stash` in any sort of automated scripts. The command has too many odd corner cases where you must do something special. Depending on which Python wrapper you have, it *might* have some compensation for these issues, but in general it just seems like a bad idea. Using `git worktree` to add a separate work-tree, in which you have full control of everything because nobody else is using that work-tree, is a better approach.

Comment: @user1245262 Sounds like you could use `git patch` instead. you can then create a patch for each result and save it to a patch file, you can apply the changes from the patch file when in need and then just checkout them. when you don't need those results anymore, just delete the patch file.